# Inserting data to mongoDB with java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and NoSQL databases at all and have some issues to working with MongoDB driver.
I don't properly understand how to get a sub-array/list from document and reinsert data in it.
This is my JSON/BSON object which i can easy save in MongoDB.

```
{
"_id": {
"$oid": "5757df25612c2445af329111"
},
"shop": {
"category": [
  {
    "MobilePhones": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "TV-sets": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "Motherboards": [

    ]
  }
]
}
}
```

Now i need to get an Array of Categories from my Shop, get object as MobilePhones/TV-sets/Motherboards category from this array/list as i write in my java POJO class.

```
public class Category extends BasicDBObject implements Serializable {

private List<Goods> goodsList;

private BasicDBObject basicDBObject;

public BasicDBObject getBasicDBObject() {
    return basicDBObject;
}

public void setBasicDBObject(BasicDBObject basicDBObject) {
    this.basicDBObject = basicDBObject;
}

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<Goods> getGoodsList() {
    return goodsList;
}

public void setGoodsList(List<Goods> goodsList) {
    this.goodsList = goodsList;
}

public Category(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public Category(){}
}
```

And insert goods into this category as i write in

```
public class Goods extends BasicDBObject implements Serializable {

private String title;

private int price;

private String status;

private BasicDBObject basicDBObject;

public BasicDBObject getBasicDBObject() {
    return basicDBObject;
}

public void setBasicDBObject(BasicDBObject basicDBObject) {
    this.basicDBObject = basicDBObject;
}

public Goods(String title, int price, String status) {
    this.title = title;
    this.price = price;
    this.status = status;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
}
```

In this way i get/create collection at database

```
 DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("shop");
 BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
 dbObject.put("shop", shop.createCategoriesWithGoods());
 collection.insert(dbObject);
```

But this way doesn't help me to get category as

```
 DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("MobilePhones");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because a collection is a table (in SQL terms) so `db.getCollection("MobilePhones");` is looking for a "table" called MobilePhones.

You have saved your data into a collection called "Shop". You need to call `getCollection("Shop")` then you can perform whatever operations you need to on the data.